# Showing solution to $y'=y$ is never zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is there a simple Calc I level (i.e., IVT and MVT) way to show that if $y'=y$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then $y$ is either identically zero or nowhere zero?

One way is to use the fact that $e^x$ is a solution; then if $g$ is another solution, $(ge^{-x})'\equiv 0$, so $g=Ce^x.$

Is there a simple way to show this using only the relation $y'=y$, the MVT, and the IVT?

As stated in a comment, my issue is how to rule out something which is zero then transitions to an increasing/decreasing function.  I feel like there should be a simple way to rule this out without using the fact that $e^x$  is a solution.

Comment: How can it possibly be simpler than this?

Comment: You could use the uniqueness of this ODE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y(x_0)>0$ then $y(x)>0$ for all $x>x_0$. Take $[y=0]$ the zero set of $y$, and pick its maximum element $z$(it exists since $[y=0]$ is closed and bounded from above). From continuity $y$ is positive on $(z,\infty)$, and is also increasing there.

Now use the IVT on $(z,z+1/2)$ and obtain
$$y(z+1/2)=\frac{1}{2}y'(\xi)=\frac{1}{2}y(\xi), \, \xi \in (z,z+1/2).$$

A contradiction since the motonicity implies $y(z+1/2)>y(\xi)$.

Comment: Shouldn't that equality be $2y'(\xi)$ if you're dividing by $1/2$?

Comment: @AdamHughes MVT on $(z,z+1/2)$ therefore $$   \frac{f(z+1/2)}{1/2+z-z}    =y'(\xi)$$

Comment: @clark oh yes, I just mis-juggled the fractions, my bad @_@

Answer (score 4):

If there is some $x_0$ for which $y(x)>0$ then as $y'(x_0)>0$, $y(x)>0$ for all $x>x_0$. On the other hand, if in addition, there is some $x_1<x_0$ for which $y(x_1)<0$ then $y'(x_1)<0$ and forever after $y$ is decreasing, so it could never increase to $y(x_0)>0$ a contradiction.

To rule out a case where $y=0$ for a long time then suddenly goes up or down, let's WLOG assume it suddenly increases and becomes positive (the other case is symmetric). Then there is some maximum $x_0$ for which $y(x)=0$ for $x\le x_0$ and positive ever after. But then let $x_0<x_1$ and consider ${y(x_1)-y(x_0)\over x_2-x_1}={y(x_1)\over x_1-x_0} =y'(c) =y(c) $ for some $x_0<c<x_1$ by assumption. Choose $0<x_1-x_0<1$ so that $y(x_1)<y(c)$ a contradiction to monotonicity.

---

Also, an alternative proof I thought up while working on the technical one:

Consider $f(x) = \log y(x)$ so that $f'(x) ={y'\over y}\equiv 1$. But then if $x_0$ is the largest real number for which $y(x) = 0$ we have that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = -\infty$, however $f'(x) \equiv 1$ verifies that $f(x) = x+c$ to the right of $x_0$, that is $\log y(x) = ce^{x}$ (without assuming it a priori!). Then the limits and derivatives agree to the right of $x_0$, implying that

$$\lim_{x\to x_0^+} y = \lim_{x\to x_0}ce^x= ce^{x_0}>0$$

showing it's impossible for $y(x_0)=0$ because continuity (given because the function is differentiable) implies the limit is equal to the value.

Comment: This is along the lines of the proof I wanted.  But my problem is, how do we rule out something which is zero for $x<c$ and increases for $x>c$?

Comment: @TorsionSquid see my edit.

Comment: Why is the derivative strictly increasing?

Comment: same reason as $y>0$ from before, if it's ever positive it is ever after, it could also be identically negative, but the proofs are symmetric. That's the beauty of $y^{(n)}=y$ they all share a common sign.

Comment: This sounds circular.  You're using the assumption $y>0$, but that's what we want to show. This is why this problem is bugging me, I feel like it should be simpler.

Comment: @TorsionSquid where? It's using one idea to the max, yes, but it's not circular. I'll put more details in to show you.

Comment: Again, $y'$ might be something flat then increasing. I don't see how you rule this out.

Comment: @TorsionSquid there you go, I finished the nitty gritty of the first proof and even added an alternative just using the first paragraph to conclude it's positive at some point (again, negative is analogous) and you actually prove in the process that $ce^x$ is a solution, but do not assume it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $y(x_0)=0.$ For any $x\ne x_0$ let $$M_x=\sup \{|y(t)|: |t-x_0|\leq |x-x_0|\}.$$ We have $M_x<\infty$ because $y$ is continuous and $\{t:|t-x_0|\leq |x-x_0|\}$ is a closed bounded interval.

For any $r>0$ take $n\in \mathbb N$ where $n$ is large enough that $$M_x|x-x_0|^{n+1}/(n+1)!<r.$$ We have $$|y(x)|=|y(x_0)+\left(\sum_{j=1}^n(x-x_0)^jy^{(j)}(x_0)\right) +y^{(n+1)}(t)(x-x_0)^{n+1}/(n+1)!|$$ for some $t$ such that $|t-x_0|<|x-x_0|.$

But $y(x_0)=0,$ and $y^{(j)}(x_0)=y(x_0)=0 $ for $1\leq j\leq n,$ so  $$|y(x)|=|y^{(n+1)}(t)(x-x_0)^{n+1}/(n+1)!.$$  But $|y^{(n+1)}(t)|=|y(t)|\leq M_x$ so $$|y(x)|\leq M_x|x-x_0|^{n+1}/(n+1)!<r.$$ Since $|y(x)|<r$ for every $r>0,$ therefore $y(x)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

If $y' = y$,
then, differentiating,
$y'' = y' = y$;
by induction,
$y^{(n)} = y$
for all $n$.

If
$y(a) = 0$,
then
$y^{(n)}(a) = 0$
for all $n$,
so $y$ is constant zero.

Comment: Here we use that $y$ is analytic.

Comment: Yes...without that assumption, it could be that all the derivatives are zero yet $y$ is not identically zero.